# Laravel can migrate but still PDOException

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I can migrate my migrations to the database, but when I access the public folder, I get a `PDOException` with:

`SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Really strange, because the migrations use the same information and still it is throwing the error.

Did this happen to someone else before?

Comment: That error is referring to MySQL user permissions. It looks like your database config is set up to log in as "root" with no password. Is that correct? One reason why migrations might work while page access does not may be because you have multiple configurations and Laravel is using one for the migration and a different one for serving pages - is that the case?

Comment: Well, to be honest I have no clue why it does log in as 'root' without a password..

Comment: Look at your app configuration. The default database configuration is in `app/config/database.php`. If you have other environments set up, like "local", you'll have a file `app/config/local/database.php` which overrides the defaults. Laravel will detect the environment and choose a configuration accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a local environment setup. The default environment is production. So if you just run "php artisan migrate" you'll be using the /app/config/database.php file but if you are on your local environment, the site will use /app/config/local/database.php

Comment: Well, I've changed my local settings as well and it works, even when I'm in the production environment.. 
When I use `php artisan env`, the environment is production, but it still uses the local/database.php settings. This shouldn't happen I guess?